# Using parent id in child query?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT li_1.carrier, li_1.product_id, li_1.quantity, products_description.products_name, sites.sites_id, sites.sites_name, counted_table.counted
FROM inventory li_1
INNER JOIN products_description ON li_1.product_id = products_description.products_id
INNER JOIN sites ON products_description.data = sites.data
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT SUM( li_2.quantity ) AS counted
   FROM inventory li_2
   WHERE li_1.product_id = li_2.product_id
) counted_table
GROUP BY li_1.product_id
ORDER BY li_1.id DESC
```

I'm attempting to use the parent id (product_id) to count the total amount of quantity for each product in the subquery - But I only get the standard mysql error message.

So something like

```
   id   |   quantity    |   total
---------------------------------
0001    |       2       |   6
        |               |
0001    |       4       |   6
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: That GROUP BY is invalid. Will raise an error on newer MySQL versions (unless in compatibility mode), and return unpredictable data with older versions. The general GROUP BY rule says: "If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function."

Comment: Read my comment one more time....

Comment: @jarlh My bad - Fixed it :-) Still same problem though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you change sub-query, it could be fixed

```
SELECT li_1.carrier, li_1.product_id, li_1.quantity, products_description.products_name, sites.sites_id, sites.sites_name, counted_table.counted
FROM inventory li_1
INNER JOIN products_description ON li_1.product_id = products_description.products_id
INNER JOIN sites ON products_description.data = sites.data
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT product_id,SUM( li_2.quantity ) AS counted
   FROM inventory li_2
   GROUP BY li_2.product_id   
) counted_table ON li_1.product_id = counted_table.product_id
ORDER BY li_1.id DESC
```